# Investment advice

Tags: english, formation-of-numbers

I'm considering investing my money with a London broker who offers excellent returns. But the only information I can find about the investment are two numerical codes:

> Deposits: 3.428571428571...
>      Withdrawals: 15724799

Should I invest my money there?

Comment: you should absolutely invest money with a broker that likes to obfuscate his results.

Comment: Sorry - I VTC as off topic before I saw the answer :)

Comment: Don't invest your money with ANY fund manager. Read Random walk down Wall Street by malkiel. Basically no one can beat the market so just invest in the market benchmark index - i.e. An ETF

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat, this is not a real investment opportunity (otherwise, it would be on a different Stack Exchange site).  It's on Puzzling, so that means it's a brain teaser.  Try to figure out the hidden meaning.  In this case, another user has already come up with the answer.  If you can't figure it out, you can read the Answer below.

Comment: Oh I see. The private message was truncated in the mobile app so I couldn't fully read why it was deleted. I think the title caught my attention without me knowing what site the question was it. So I'll blame the mobile app :)

Comment: Still solid advice though. I too have been confused by the stackexchange switcheroo. Confusing the sci-fi and physics exchanges can lead to WTF moments.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, you should not invest with them!

They will ask for your deposits all day, every day,

> 3.428571428571 = 24/7, as in 24 hours per day, 7 days a week

but if you ask for a withdrawal, they turn you away! And instead, they will tell you to

> EFF OFF (or EFF0FF, which is hexidecimal for 15724799)